# Keeping track of touched points in mutable array

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uiview

UPDATE: I realized that the "initWithFrame" method is never called, so I placed my array's init elsewhere. Thanks for reading. (for anyone, what's the point of initWithFrame if it is not called?"

I've been staring at this code for about an hour and am probably missing a simple and obvious issue. I'm merely trying to keep an array of touched points. My UIView's init says this:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
}
self.drawn=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init ];
return self;
}
```

Then I have this in another method:

```
CGPoint point=[[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
NSLog(@"touched point: %f, %f",point.x,point.y);
[self.drawn addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point]];
```

The NSLog confirms that "point" exists and contains x and y data.

Why then does my "drawn" array never get anything? I have read the NSValue tutorials and I seem to be doing this correctly. An NSLog of [self.drawn count] always shows 0 despite that this code has triggered.

And of course "drawn" is also an ivar of my custom UIView, properly synthesized also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `initWithFrame:` never gets called,* and `drawn` is never created. From the [Resource Management Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH4-SW18):

> In iOS, any object that conforms to the `NSCoding` protocol is initialized using the `initWithCoder:` method. This includes all subclasses of `UIView`[...] Custom views in iOS do not use the `initWithFrame:` method for initialization.

The value at `drawn` is therefore `nil`, and calling `[nil count]` gives `0`; `[nil addObject:]` similarly does nothing.

That said, your `initWithFrame:` also has two memory problems. Your assignment to the property over-retains the array, and you should be doing that assignment inside the `if` block.

When you create an `NSMutableArray` using `alloc`/`init`, you own that array. When you then assign it using a property which is defined as retaining, you have an extra claim on that object, which can eventually cause a leak.

Second: if, for whatever reason, the call to `[super initWithFrame:frame]` fails, `self` will be invalid (`nil`), and using one of its properties will likewise be incorrect. That's the purpose of `if(self)`.
You should do this instead:

```
if(self){
    self.drawn = [NSMutableArray array];
}
```

This creates an autoreleased `NSMutableArray` which your view then properly retains.

---

*I wish I knew why too. It *does* get used in OS X.

Answer (score 0):

I would check if the

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
```

is called.

Comment: indeed, that is exactly what I discovered, probably just while you were typing this! thanks.

Comment: I see you are new to stackOverFlow. If you wish to get answers in the future you should approve answers you approve as correct. simply check the white check mark in the left side of the answer.

Comment: Hi Shani, Yes I have always approved answers in any question I ask here. Thanks.